# Android ExampleInstrumentedTest running fails with "Test framework quit unexpectedly"

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-instrumentation

Error for all of my androidTests:

```
05/01 21:24:26: Launching 'ExampleInstrumentedT...' on Nexus 5 API R.
Install successfully finished in 1 s 870 ms.
Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -m    -e debug false -e class 'com.mrahimy.mytestapplication10.ExampleInstrumentedTest' com.mrahimy.mytestapplication10.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Test running failed: Process crashed.
Tests ran to completion.
```

The message here says: `Test running failed: Process crashed.`

There is another related message in the logcat:

```
RuntimeException: Unable to find instrumentation info for: 
ComponentInfo{com.mrahimy.mytestapplication10.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

This is just the template project which is created by choosing "Fragment + ViewModel" or "No Activity" in `file -> new project` in Android Studio 4.1.3

The example instrumented test is just as it was. No changes were made by me. The gradle wrapper version is `gradle-6.5-bin.zip`. the kotlin version is 1.4.32 and gradle tools version is 4.1.3

I have searched stackoverflow and the answers either apply to previous versions of Android Studio or the question is from an entire different framework.

So what can I do to see what is wrong with the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

Firstly, I changed my emulator and used one with API 28 and it went well.
However, a benchmark module could not also run for any API level emulator or a physical device. But I removed this dependency from my gradle script and it is now working good:

`androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:2.7.0-alpha04`

Comment: good one! I tried everything, changing the emulator to API 28 worked